# Bug while using ngRepeat. Set checkboxes and radio buttons checked in a wrong way

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of users in the controller of the component. I've tried to print it using ngRepeat directive. There're following bugs in the final result:

- According to array of users there should be the only one with checked `active` (the second).
- There should be the second radio button checked instead of the third one.
  [image: Rendered result(wrong)]

I have the following list of users' objects:

```
$scope.users = [
                 {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'John',
                    birthday: '06.07.2008',
                    city: 'Budapest',
                    active: false,
                    boss: false
                 },
                 {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Mary',
                    birthday: '01.02.2003',
                    city: 'Berlin',
                    active: true,
                    boss: true
                 },
                 {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'James',
                    birthday: '04.05.2006',
                    city: 'Vienna',
                    active: false,
                    boss: false
                 }
            ];
```

Functions that check both statuses of each user:

```
            $scope.isActive = function (id) {
                return $scope.users[id].active;
            }

            $scope.isBoss = function (id) {
                console.log(id);
                return $scope.users[id].boss;
            }
```

The actual template(view):

```
<tbody>
        <div>
            <tr ng-click="goToProfile(user.id)" ng-repeat="user in users">
                <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.birthday}}</td>
                <td>{{user.city}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="active" ng-checked="{ checked: isActive($index) }">
                    <h1>{{isActive($index)}}</h1>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="boss" ng-checked="{ checked: isBoss($index) }">
                    <h1>{{isBoss($index)}}</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </tbody>
```

I've done some test prints to make sure that it reads needed fields correctly. The actual result you can see on the screenshot and in the code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never seen your use of ng-checked before. Looking at the documentation ["Sets the checked attribute on the element, if the expression inside ngChecked is truthy."](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked), I suppose that you shouldn't have an object as your expression, just your function call. Then the radio buttons would not all be checked, because it's the behavior of radio buttons to let only one of a group be checked at a time.

Comment: @raichu I know the actual behavior of radio button inputs. Read the question first. Also your answer solves the problem. Create new answer to the question so I can mark it as correct one.

Comment: I would let angular do its work like in @atcastroviejo's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set a name to the radio button, that made them part of the same group, which did not allow multiple radio buttons to be checked at the same time.

In addition, `ng-checked` should receive an expression, in this case the function call.

The following code suits your needs.

```
<tr ng-click="goToProfile(user.id)" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.birthday}}</td>
    <td>{{user.city}}</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="active" ng-checked="isActive($index)">
      <h1>{{isActive($index)}}</h1>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" ng-checked="isBoss($index)">
      <h1>{{isBoss($index)}}</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using

```
$scope.users[id]
```

to access the user with a given id. But what you pass is not an id. It's an index. That makes your code confusing. You should pass the user itself, instead of its index. And in fact, you don't even need these functions at all, since you can just just `user.active`, and `user.boss`.

You don't need ng-checked either. Just use ng-model

```
<tr ng-click="goToProfile(user)" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.birthday }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.city }}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="active" ng-model="user.active">
        <h1>{{ user.active }}</h1>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="boss" ng-model="user.boss">
        <h1>{{ user.boss }}</h1>
    </td>
```

Note that I changed the radio to a checkbox, since two of your users are bosses, and it thus not make much sense to use a radio button.

If you want a radio button, then the model should be adapted; you should have an attribute in the scope referencing the unique user being the boss:

```
$scope.model = {
    boss: $scope.users.filter(function(user) {
        return user.boss;
    })[0]
};
```

and in your view:

```
<input type="radio" name="boss" ng-model="model.boss" ng-value="user"/>
```

Comment: I've done some edits on my question correcting users' list so now it has only one boss at the time. The problem is that I need to use radio button and it seems like `ng-model="users.boss"` is not working with radio button. After doing everything you wrote in your answer (except of changing radiobutton to checkbox) no radio button is checked now: http://prntscr.com/dkj3qh

Comment: Fine! But it finds out that there's no adaption needed if replace `ng-model` with `ng-checked`

Comment: Have you tried checking the checkboses and radio buttons and see what happens?

Comment: Yes. But what exactly do you mean?

Comment: That the accepted answer won't change the model when the checkboxes and radio buttons are checked, making them basically useless.

Comment: Ok. Your answer works on input.checkbox: it changes the value of active. But it doesn't work on input.radio

Comment: It does. As explained, it will set the value of $scope.model.boss. Up to you to adapt the model used by the form to your own model where only one of the users has a true boss flag. You should take a step back and start reading documentation about angular forms, ng-model, the input[type=radio], etc., instead of expecting a ready-to-use solution that you don't understand and won't be able to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use *ng-model="user.active"* in the checkbox. No functions needed.

The same goes for the input radio.

Hope this helps. Check out the angular documentation for inputs.